# Изменение значения по ссылке

Tags: java

Всем привет, по задумке нужно было получить из метода контейнера ссылку на объект, по ссылке его изменить и убедиться , что он изменен,повторно получив ссылку. 
Однако поменять значение , используя следующий способ не получается

```
SingleList<String> list = new SingleList<String>();
list.add("Hello");
String string = list.elementAt(0);
string = string +  ", world!";
System.out.println(list.elementAt(0));
```

Но если ввести дополнительный класс, то все работает.

```
class MyStr
{
    public String str = new String();
    MyStr(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
SingleList<MyStr> list = new SingleList<MyStr>();
list.add(new MyStr("Hello"));
MyStr string = list.elementAt(0);
string.str = string.str +  ", world!";
System.out.println(list.elementAt(0).str);
```

В чем принципиальное различие между 1 и 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Принципиальная разница в том, что в первом случае, объект `string` является неизменяемым, в отличии от второго случая.

В Java строки является неизменяемыми (*immutable*), и в этой строке:

```
string = string +  ", world!";
```

при попытке изменения строки (в данном случае, при конкатенации) создается новый объект (отличный от того, что находится в списке) и `string` уже ссылается на этот созданный новый объект.

Во втором случае, у Вас в списке хранятся объекты типа `MyStr` и при изменении значения поля этого объекта, сам объект `MyStr string` не поменяется и будет ссылаться туда, куда и ссылался прежде.